# Count the number of positive integers $i$ such that $i\cdot (N-i) \leq N\cdot K$ and $i< N$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given two integers $N$ and $K$, count the number of positive integers $i$ such that $i\cdot (N-i) \leq N\cdot K$ and $i< N$.

Input

First line contains, $T$, the number of test cases. Each test case consists of $N$ and $K$ in one line.

Output

For each test case, print in one line the required answer.

Constraints

$1 ≤ T ≤ 10^5$

$1 ≤ N,K ≤ 10^9$

Sample Input

$2$

$5\,\, 1$

$5\,\, 2$

Sample Output

$2$

$4$

Answer (score 0):

Find the roots of $i(N-i) = NK$ using the quadratic formula. Any values of $i$ strictly between the roots produce a product $i(N-i)$ that is too high. If the equation has no roots, all values of $i$ give $i(N-i) < NK$.

For example, for the $N=5$, $K=1$ test case, the equation to solve is

$$i(5-i) = 5$$

which has roots approximately $1.38$ and $3.62$. Thus, the values $i=2$ and $i=3$ don't work, but $i=1$ and $i=4$ do. The solution for this test case is $2$.

Comment: can you explain for the given test cases??

Comment: @user143268: I've added an example.

Comment: but for such a high range and counting the values between 1 to N exclusive of roots will give TLE

Comment: @user143268: You don't have to go through and actually count one by one. You can do some subtraction.

Comment: the following soln. given TLE. http://ideone.com/K1dsel

Comment: @user143268: Okay, think of it this way. How would you figure out how many integers are between 5 and 5000? You wouldn't go through and count them, would you? Make the computer do what you would do.

Comment: I changed a bit. Its giving WA. http://ideone.com/AVuBlx

Comment: @user143268: You have a boundary error. This is getting off-topic for math.stackexchange.com; try to debug the rest yourself.